# Chrome download failed in Selenium docker

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download a file with Selenium running on docker and getting the error **Failed -  insufficient permissions**
[as can be seen here, from VNC to selenium docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLsRB.png)

The python script using selenium is running in another docker and i need it to use a file download with selenium, passing it through a folder mounted to both of them with a docker volume.

That's how i'm running selenium docker:

```
docker run -d  --network host  -v /home/exports:/home/seluser/downloads:rw  -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804
```

That's how i'm running the python script using selenium:

```
docker run --network host -v /home/logs:/logs -v /home/exports:/exports -i -t automated_testing
```

Those are the chrome options in the python script:

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')      
    chrome_options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection') 
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument("test-type")
    prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": False,
    "download.prompt_for_download" : False,
    "download.directory_upgrade":  True,
    "download.default_directory" : "/home/seluser/downloads",
    'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': True,
      "safebrowsing.enabled": False
    }
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=chrome_options.to_capabilities())
    
    # Set permissions
    driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': '/home/seluser/downloads'}}
    command_result = self.driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

Just when observing the VNC i see the error of the download.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As you are running your code in standalone docker container you need not to initialize Remote driver. You can initialize chromedriver and do not use localhost:4444. This should be used when you are running automation script from host machine.

Try running above automation code from your host machine instead of triggering it in docker container.